# Confirm that middleware is in use

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, asp.net-core-middleware

I am trying to confirm via a unit test that middleware is actually being added to the pipeline. I have the following static method that adds the middleware. This is what I am testing.

```
public static class HandleDbUpdateExceptionExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseDbUpdateExceptionHandler(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<DbUpdateExceptionHandler>();
    }
}
```

I know it's actually working because the middleware runs on my site. However, I'd like to write a unit test to ensure it's always included in future builds. My unit test, however, fails:

```
[Fact(DisplayName = "Exception handler is added to IApplicationBuilder")]
public void DbUpdateExceptionHandler_Added_To_IApplicationBuilder()
{
    var builder = new Mock<IApplicationBuilder>().Object;

    builder.UseDbUpdateExceptionHandler();

    Assert.NotNull(builder.ApplicationServices);

    //var test = builder.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(DbUpdateExceptionHandler));
}
```

`builder.ApplicationServices` is null so the test currently fails. I assume that it is failing because I am just mocking `IApplicationBuilder` but there is very little relevant material online about unit testing the *existance* of .Net Core middleware.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`UseMiddleware` is actually an extension method that will create a RequestDelegate that uses your middleware internally. That delegate does quite a lot of things, so it would be very difficult for you to test that it will properly register your actual middleware type.

The only thing you can really do is to check that the underlying [`ApplicationBuilder.Use` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.applicationbuilder.use?view=aspnetcore-5.0) was called with *some* request delegate.

Alternatively, you could also actually invoke the middleware, by building the application pipeline and executing it. But that will require that you set up dependency injection properly (since the delegate from `UseMiddleware()` will use that) and that all your middleware’s dependencies are set up properly.

So this is going to be very complicated. I would suggest you to write an [integration test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-5.0) instead that checks that for a request, your middleware will be invoked properly and can do what it should do.

Comment: I was afraid of this but it appears I would have to do that to test it. It's a shame that there is not an `IApplicationBuilder` or `IServiceProvider` method that gives you the pipeline or confirms whether or not a specific class (or even interface) is in the pipeline.

Comment: Well, as I said, you can easily test that `IApplicationBuilder.Use` was called, but due to [how `UseMiddleware` works](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions/Extensions/UseMiddlewareExtensions.cs#L44), you simply won’t be able to tell that it’s the middleware of your type. At least not without actually invoking the request delegate.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @poke's answer you might want to look into [middleware analysis](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/962db1feccdfb84ca4ee28f6b3c03d66cec66e54/src/Middleware/MiddlewareAnalysis) which is part of the ASP.NET Core Diagnostics stack. There is also a [sample application](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/962db1feccdfb84ca4ee28f6b3c03d66cec66e54/src/Middleware/MiddlewareAnalysis/samples/MiddlewareAnalysisSample) available.

What it basically does is surrounding each middleware with the [`AnalysisMiddleware`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/962db1feccdfb84ca4ee28f6b3c03d66cec66e54/src/Middleware/MiddlewareAnalysis/src/AnalysisMiddleware.cs) which writes information to a diagnostics source. You could create a diagnostics source listener in your tests and validate that each middleware is invoked. However, this requires you to execute the middleware pipeline which effectively means your creating an *integration* test.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I've done it:

```
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
serviceCollection.AddSingleton(Mock.Of<ILogger<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware>>());

var applicationBuilder = new ApplicationBuilder(serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider());

applicationBuilder.UseExceptionHandlingMiddleware();

var app = applicationBuilder.Build();

app.Target.Should().BeOfType<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware>();
```

This works when there is only one middleware in the list.

Comment: What version of .Net Core do you use with this test? Doesn't work for me with .Net Core 3.1.

Comment: It is .net core 3.1

Comment: With assuming there is only one middleware in the list you cant create integration tests.